# Trying to blurr an image in C but whole row is blured same way

Tags: c, image

So I am trying to make a function that blurs an image, basically checks all pixels around it by 1 if there is adds to counter and divides total RGB and for some reason my picture comes out like this: and idk what is happening
[blurred result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcRlc.png) , I think the image is blurring whole row using same value? why is that?

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float totalRed,totalGreen,totalBlue;
            totalRed = totalGreen = totalBlue = 0;
            float counter = 0.00;

            //close pixels
            for(int x = -1; x < 2; x++)
            {
                for(int y = -1; y < 2; y++)
                {
                    int nbrX = i + x;
                    int nbrY = i + y;

                    if (nbrX < 0 || nbrX > (height - 1) || nbrY < 0 || nbrY > (width - 1))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    totalRed += image[nbrX][nbrY].rgbtRed;
                    totalGreen += image[nbrX][nbrY].rgbtGreen;
                    totalBlue += image[nbrX][nbrY].rgbtBlue;

                    counter++;

                }


                temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round(totalRed/ counter);
                temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(totalGreen/ counter);
                temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(totalBlue/ counter);
            }

        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = temp[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temp[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temp[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your variables for x/y-coordinates of the "nearby"-pixel both use "i" as reference..

```
int nbrX = j + x;
int nbrY = i + y;
```

(I'd rather have made a comment - but without reputation..)

Comment: Good spotting! Because of this, I am voting to close the question as a typo.